# C++ add 1+2+3+...+N

Tags: c++, loops

I've been having trouble with a problem from my C++ book. It wasn't required to do, but I want to get it to work:

> **Sum of numbers**
>
> Write a program that asks the users for a positive integer value and that uses a loop to validate the input.* The program should then use a second loop to compute the sum of all the integers from 1 up to the number entered. For example, if the user enters 50, the loop will find the sum of 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 50.

*I'm not asking for this first loop, just the second. But if you feel like coding it go ahead.

It's pretty simple to write a program that decreases a number until it reaches one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> number;

    while(number >= 1)
    {
        cout << number << " ";
        number--;
    }

    system("pause"); //I usually go with cin.get() but my current 
                     //compiler doesn't handle it
    return 0;
}
```

But if you to add "number - 1" to a number, the number becomes bigger and now number - 1 will increase from thereon. For example, 7 + 6 = 13, 13 + 12 = 25, 25 + 24 = 49, etc. Here's the program I am trying to adapt to make work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> number;

    for(count = 1; count <= number; count++)
    {
        number += number - 1;
    }

    cout << "The sum is" << number << endl;

    system("pause"); //
    return 0;
}
```

This is an infinite loop, unfortunately.

Any ideas to how to adapt this program so it satisfies the question? Or links to source code that's already done it before, etc.

---

EDIT:

So this might be another issue entirely, but my code isn't compiling:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    cin >> number;

    for(count = 1; count <= number; count++)
    {    
        number--;
        sum += number; 
    }

    cout << "The sum is" << sum << endl;

    system("pause"); //
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

---

EDIT 2: I just got rid of the for loop and changed it to "while(number >= 1)"

Comment: I don't like down votes, so please ask me to add or change anything first. Thank you

Comment: You need an extra variable for the sum, and decrement number as you had before.

Comment: I've tried that actually, but I haven't had much luck

Comment: Try it again.  It's not a difficult task.

Comment: ok I'll post my attempt

Comment: You had it pretty much in your first program, you just need to add somrthing like `sum += number;`. Make sure to put it in the right place to get the sum you want.

Comment: So basically, you need to know how to sum numbers from 1 to n? `int sum = 0; for(int i = 0; i <= n){ sum += i; } `. This was probably down voted because you're including irrelevant information, and it's not entirely clear what you're asking. If it is summing numbers, there are examples of that everywhere, so this question isn't really appropriate for here.

Comment: Thanks for the help to all, I've tried to take your suggestions and use them. I think my program might work after I fix some syntax error I've made in the for loop

Comment: @Zack _"but my code isn't compiling:"_ And what's the exact error message?

Comment: BTW, `1+2+3+…+N` is `N * (N + 1) / 2`.

Comment: @Zack Facepalm: `for(int count = 1; count <= number; count++)`

Comment: yeah I really just wanted to use the Leibnez summation formula, but I really need to understand loops better

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
int sum = number;
while (number-- > 0) {
    sum += number;
}
```

Comment: For those who don't get it, it basically store number, then decrease number by 1 until zero, adding it to sum at each step.

Comment: Might just be me, but I think a for loop gets the point across better, especially to a newbie. Even though I know what this means, it still looks off to me. There should at least be a space between the postfix decrementor and the greater than operator. Forming an arrow is an unnecessary obfuscation imo.

Comment: thx to SergeyBrunov for editing my code as proposed by @Carcigenicate =) I wasn't aware of this arrow until you told about it  xD

Comment: For a second, I though that `-->` was a new operator or something. Took me a little longer than it should have to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I find a for loop neater, so I'll post an example for variety.

```
int n = Max Number
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

And for your compiling problem, unless I'm reading it wrong, you shouldn't be decrementing the number; it's defining what the max number is. Each loop you're incrementing the count, decrementing the number, then comparing them. I can't imagine that will give you anything meaningful. Erase the `number--;`, and it should work.